# UILabel displaying (null) in custom UItableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, tableview

I can't figure out why my UILabels in my custom `TableViewCell` are nil in CellForRowAtIndexPath. I used the same method as I did for a previous TableView in another view Controller. Here's what I already checked:

- Cell Style is Custom
- Cell has a unique identifier "profilecell"
- Cell's class is of the desired custom type
- data source and delegated are connected to the View Controller
- Each of the 5 buttons/labels is connected to its respective property in the custom class
- Dynamic Prototypes is selected

I am able to change the background color of the cell and populate the textLabel.text -- it's just my `UILabels` that aren't filled.

Here is `CellForRowAtIndexPath`. It's the exact same method as my other `TableVC`, which works. Also, I don't need to actually reuse this custom cell, should I be using a different method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifierProfile = @"profilecell";
ProfileSection0TableViewCell *profilecell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierProfile];

     if (profilecell == nil) {
        profilecell = [[ProfileSection0TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierProfile];
     }

     if (indexPath.section == 0) {
         [profilecell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:54/255.0f green:61/255.0f blue:147/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

         if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            profilecell.labelName.text = _userProfile.fullName;
            NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", profilecell.labelName.text];
            NSLog(@"text %@", test); //shows that label is (null)

            profilecell.labelName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            //profilecell.labelSpecialty.text = _userProfile.specialty;
            //profilecell.labelSpecialty.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        }
    }
    return profilecell;
}
```

Thanks so much in advance.

.h file:

```
    @interface ProfileSection0TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* labelName;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* labelSpecialty;
    @property (nonatomic, weak ) IBOutlet UILabel* labelCurrentRole;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* labelPosition;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton* facePicture;
    @end
```

.m file:

```
    @implementation ProfileSection0TableViewCell
    @synthesize  labelName, labelSpecialty, labelPosition, facePicture, labelCurrentRole;

    @end
```

EDIT:

It looks like ProfileSection0TableViewCell is allocated properly, but the member vars inside the cell are nil. And in outlets, here are the connections:

- facePicture - Button
- labelName- UILabel "person"
- labelPosition - UILabel "position"
- List item - UILabel "specialty"
- labelCurrentRole - UILabel titled school

Comment: What about the value of the variable `_userProfile.fullName` and can you share how you setup the `UILabel` _labelName_  in your custom `UITableViewCell` class _ProfileSection0TableViewCell_

Comment: _userProfile.fullName isn't null -- it has all the correct data in the object

Comment: According to your comment after the `NSLog`, your test shows that the `NSString *` named `test` is `nil`, NOT that the cell's `labelName` label is `nil`. You need to dig a little deeper. Are you certain that the `profileCell` is not also  `nil` ? What about the cell's IBOutlets? Are they hooked up correctly?

Comment: @Aaron IBOutlets are all good. profileCell is initialized but labelName never gets set. Is it possible I'm overwriting data somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Either `_userProfile.fullName` is `nil` or `profilecell.labelName` is `nil`

If you made the cell in interface builder, did you hook up the outlet to `labelName` correctly?

Comment: I agree, how are you setting `_userProfile.fullName`? That appears to be the weak link in your code, without seeing where that variable is set.

Comment: _userProfile is a property in the TVC, populated by jSON data, and fullname has the correct text in it when I go through with the debugger. I was also able to set the cell.TextLabel.text to _userProfile.fullName with no problems